# Succinct way to set multiple factor levels of different variables to same color in ggplot scatterplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot, factors

Consider the following simplified dataframe:

```
x =  c(.35, .35, .37, .5, .55, .56, .9, .91, .89)
y = c(.35, .36, .35, .22, .27, .25, .88, .9, .87)
clu3 = as.factor(c(31,31,31,32,32,32,33,33,33))
clu4 = as.factor(c(41,41,41,42,43,43,44,44,44))

df = data.frame (x,y,clu3,clu4)
```

In my analysis, three clusters are first fit to the dataset (clu3, which has factor levels 31, 32, and 33). Four clusters are then fit to the dataset as well (clu4, which has factor levels 41, 42, 43, 44), and then five clusters, and six clusters, and so on. I've only included the results from fitting three and four clusters for simplicity.

I can plot the results for each "run" (i.e., the three cluster run and the four cluster run) using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=clu3)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle(paste("Three-cluster scatterplot"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=clu4)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle(paste("Four-cluster scatterplot"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Right now, I'm specifying cluster color in ggplot. But in my example, clusters 31 and 41 are identical (but from different "runs") and clusters 33 and 44 are identical as well. There are additional identical clusters in later runs as well (when fitting five clusters to the data, six, etc.). What I would like to do is specify the color of factor levels of different variables (clu3 and clu4, in this case) in a succinct way. Perceptually, it would be something like:

```
"31" | "41" = "purple"
"33" | "44" = "green"
"32"        = "blue"
"42"        = "orange"
"43"        = "yellow"
```

I'm guessing the solution involves scale_fill_manual, and I've read up on ways to get factor level colors consistent across plots (even if some factor levels aren't used). But in all of those examples, the factor levels are of the **same** variable, whereas I want to make **different factor levels from different variables consistent colors**. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that clusters 31 and 41 are identical or clusters 33 and 44 are identical ?

Comment: It's less clear in this toy example, but in my real dataset I calculate the Euclidean distance between cluster centroids to assess which ones are duplicates. I iteratively fit 2:9 clusters to the dataset so there are inevitably some clusters that are almost identical. Now, I'd like to track those clusters in each run which is why I was hoping to set cluster color in a clean way.

Comment: So do you mean you will manually identify such clusters and want to change the colors used for them?

Comment: Hi Ronak, yes. I manually identify duplicate clusters. As of right now, I have to specify the color for every single cluster to get the ones IDed as duplicates to be the same color across plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, using `scale_fill_manual` or `scale_color_manual` is a valid option.
You could write a function that matches the colors between two clusterings (e.g. relative to the clusters of the first or previous clustering).

Here is one way you could match up the colors and apply that to multiple clusters sequentially:

```r
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(.35, .35, .37, .5, .55, .56, .9, .91, .89)
y <- c(.35, .36, .35, .22, .27, .25, .88, .9, .87)
clu3 <- factor(c(31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33))
clu4 <- factor(c(41, 41, 41, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44))
clu5 <- factor(c(51, 51, 52, 53, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55)) # added a few more clusters
clu6 <- factor(c(61, 61, 62, 63, 64, 64, 65, 66, 65))
df <- data.frame(x, y, clu3, clu4, clu5, clu6)

## assign specific colors to matching clusters; rest: use same colors
matchCol <- function(fac1, fac2, pal=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9",
                                       "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2",
                                       "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")){
    maxl <- max(length(levels(fac1)), length(levels(fac2)))
    if(length(pal) < maxl) { # make sure you have enough colors
        warning("Not enough colors; using scales::hue_pal")
        pal <- scales::hue_pal()(maxl)
    }
    tab <- as.matrix(table(fac1, fac2)) > 0
    rs1 <- which(rowSums(tab) == 1)
    rs2 <- apply(tab[rs1, , drop=FALSE], 1, which.max)
    f1 <- setNames(pal[seq_along(levels(fac1))], levels(fac1))
    f2 <- setNames(NA[seq_along(levels(fac2))], levels(fac2))
    f2[levels(fac2)[rs2]] <- f1[levels(fac1)[rs1]]              # add matching colors
    f2n <- names(f2)
    if(!identical(fac1, fac2)) f2n[rs2] <- paste0(levels(fac1)[rs1], " | ", levels(fac2)[rs2])
    f2[is.na(f2)] <- setdiff(pal, f2)[seq_along(f2[is.na(f2)])] # fill in remaining colors
    list(fac1=f1, fac2=f2, f2n=f2n )     # you only need f2 here, so could simplify
}

# then plot using matchCol function, e.g.:
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=clu4)) + 
    geom_point(size=4)+
    theme_bw()+
    ggtitle(paste("Four-cluster scatterplot"))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=matchCol(clu3, clu4)$fac2,
                       labels=matchCol(clu3, clu4)$f2)
```

[image]

```r
# or generalized
clusts <- grep("clu", colnames(df), value=TRUE)
p1 <- lapply(clusts, function(z){
    mc <- matchCol(get(clusts[1]), get(z)) 
    ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=z)) + 
        geom_point(size=4)+
        theme_bw()+
        ggtitle(paste0(gsub("clu", "", z),"-cluster scatterplot"))+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values=mc$fac2, labels=mc$f2)
    }
)
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = p1)
```

[image]

```r
# same, relative to previous clustering:
p2 <- lapply(seq_along(clusts), function(z){
    mc <- matchCol(get(clusts[max(1, z-1)]), get(clusts[z]))
    ggplot(df, aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=clusts[z])) + 
        geom_point(size=4)+
        theme_bw()+
        ggtitle(paste0(gsub("clu", "", clusts[z]),"-cluster scatterplot"))+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values=mc$fac2, labels=mc$f2)
  }
)
    
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = p2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: this solution works for the two-cluster case in your example data. You will need to use different logic (other than first/last) to create `new_clu` for > 2 clusters.*

One solution is to convert the data to "long" form, group by `x` and `y`, then create a new variable `new_clu` based on the values of `clu3` and `clu4`.

Notes: I'm using `gather` but you could use the newer `pivot_longer`. A warning will be generated about non-identical attributes, it can be ignored.

```
df %>% 
  gather(Cluster, Val, 3:4) %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(new_clu = case_when(
    first(Val) == 31 & last(Val) == 41 ~ paste0(first(Val), "/", last(Val)),
    first(Val) == 33 & last(Val) == 44 ~ paste0(first(Val), "/", last(Val)),
    TRUE ~ Val
  )
)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   x, y [9]
       x     y Cluster Val   new_clu
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
 1  0.35  0.35 clu3    31    31/41  
 2  0.35  0.36 clu3    31    31/41  
 3  0.37  0.35 clu3    31    31/41  
 4  0.5   0.22 clu3    32    32     
 5  0.55  0.27 clu3    32    32     
 6  0.56  0.25 clu3    32    32     
 7  0.9   0.88 clu3    33    33/44  
 8  0.91  0.9  clu3    33    33/44  
 9  0.89  0.87 clu3    33    33/44  
10  0.35  0.35 clu4    41    31/41  
11  0.35  0.36 clu4    41    31/41  
12  0.37  0.35 clu4    41    31/41  
13  0.5   0.22 clu4    42    42     
14  0.55  0.27 clu4    43    43     
15  0.56  0.25 clu4    43    43     
16  0.9   0.88 clu4    44    33/44  
17  0.91  0.9  clu4    44    33/44  
18  0.89  0.87 clu4    44    33/44
```

Now you can pass that to `ggplot` and color on `new_clu`:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Cluster, Val, 3:4) %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(new_clu = case_when(
    first(Val) == 31 & last(Val) == 41 ~ paste0(first(Val), "/", last(Val)),
    first(Val) == 33 & last(Val) == 44 ~ paste0(first(Val), "/", last(Val)),
    TRUE ~ Val
  )
) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
geom_point(aes(color = new_clu))
```

Result:

[image]